# Print elements from array of matrices in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, printf

I am trying to print each char of an array of matrices for a brick breaker game (the full message would be YOU LOSE). I am new to C and I don't feel too confident about using pointers; I feel that that may be the source of my problem. To try to solve the problem, I've read plenty of online guides on how to deal with strings in C; but the fact that I'm dealing with an array of arrays of arrays of chars makes this task quite a bit harder. If you know how to print matrices of strings (in yet another array) in C, or you have a better solution, please let me know!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LETTER_WIDTH 13
#define LETTER_HEIGHT 6

char Y[LETTER_HEIGHT][LETTER_WIDTH] = {
"___      __\n",
"\\ \\__ / /\n",
"\\ \\ / /\n",
"|  |  |\n",
"|  |  |\n",
"|__|__|\n"};

char O[LETTER_HEIGHT][LETTER_WIDTH] = {
"  _______ \n",
" /  __   \\\n",
"|  |  |   |\n",
"|  |__|   |\n",
" \\_______/\n"};

char *SENTENCE[2][LETTER_HEIGHT][LETTER_WIDTH] = {*Y, *O};

void printLetter(char letter[LETTER_HEIGHT][LETTER_WIDTH]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < LETTER_HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < LETTER_WIDTH; j++) {
            printf("%c", letter[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void printSentence() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        char letter[LETTER_HEIGHT][LETTER_WIDTH];
        strcpy(*letter, **SENTENCE[i]);
        printLetter(letter);
        sleep(1);
    }
}


int main() {
    printSentence();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 - I don't care about that at the moment, all I want to achieve right now is the ability to print one letter fully, and then another letter fully (I'll be implementing this in curses so I can clear the screen before each print)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly this should be better

```c
char* Y[LETTER_HEIGHT] = {
"___      __\n",
"\\ \\__ / /\n",
"\\ \\ / /\n",
"|  |  |\n",
"|  |  |\n",
"|__|__|\n"};

char* O[LETTER_HEIGHT] = {
"  _______ \n",
" /  __   \\\n",
"|  |  |   |\n",
"|  |__|   |\n",
" \\_______/\n"};
```

Now these are arrays of size 6 (you must add one line because O now have height of 5) containing pointers to arrays of chars. Next

```c
char** SENTENCE[2] = {Y, O};
```

You did some really weird things with this line before, this defines SENTENCE as 2 element array of pointers to array of pointers to char arrays (which are Y and O).
Next

```c
void printLetter(char** letter) {
    for (int i = 0; i < LETTER_HEIGHT; i++) {
        printf("%s", letter[i]);
    }
}
```

This function takes pointer to array of pointers to char arrays. Then goes 6 times and print each array as string. Next

```c
void printSentence() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printLetter(SENTENCE[i]);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Here you can use simple for loop to pass to printLetter each pointer to array of pointers to char arrays (which are these letters) from SENTENCE.

Answer (score 1):

> *or you have a better solution, please let me know!*

Yes, there is a much simpler and, I would argue, better solution, it's to place the `SENTENCE` in a single 2D array and print it in one go, even if you are to use ncurses, this makes your job easier.

Note that with ncurses you can reposition the cursor so you can print each letter separately in one line, you wouldn't need to join them together like you try to do in `SENTENCE`.

```
#define LETTER_WIDTH 100
#define LETTER_HEIGHT 6

char SENTENCE[LETTER_HEIGHT][LETTER_WIDTH] = {
    "__    __   ______ \n",
    "\\ \\  / /  /  __  \\\n",
    " \\ \\/ /   | |  | |\n", 
    "  |  |    | |  | |\n",
    "  |  |    | |__| |\n",
    "  |__|    \\______/\n"};
    

void printSentence()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", SENTENCE[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
__    __   ______
\ \  / /  /  __  \
 \ \/ /   | |  | |
  |  |    | |  | |
  |  |    | |__| |
  |__|    \______/
```

Comment: This seems to work just as fine, but part of my problem (that I didn't post here) was that I wanted to scale the spacing between the letters depending on the screen size; but this is pretty cool as well!